# How do I get the Intellij code autoformatter to keep an annotated field on one line?

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting

Whenever I run the IntelliJ autoformatter - it converts this:

```
@Autowired private CustomerDao customerDao;
```

into this:

```
@Autowired 
private CustomerDao customerDao;
```

How can I stop it from doing that?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Navigate to **Preferences → Editor → Code Style → Java → Wrapping and Braces tab**, then locate the section **Field annotations** and check the option **Do not wrap after single annotation**.

In IntelliJ v14:

[image: eIntelliJ v14 Java style preferences]

Comment: could you add a text explaination too? The image can not be found anymore (404). Thanks!

Comment: @crush sorry for that, it's the hoster issue, I'll try to make a new screenshot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284911/intellij-code-formatting-java-annotations-on-new-lines

Answer (score 0):

For me works well:
Preferences → Editor → Code Style → Java → Wrapping and Braces → Method annotations → wrap always