# Intellij code formatting, Java annotations on new lines

Tags: java, formatting, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ 12 and 
It's putting my member variable annotations on the same line, which i hate! How do I setup the code formatter to keep annotations on separate lines?

thanks!

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Navigate to **Preferences → Editor → Code Style → Java → Wrapping and Braces tab**, then locate the section **Field annotations** and check the option **Do not wrap after single annotation**.

In IntelliJ v14:

[image: eIntelliJ v14 Java style preferences]

Comment: If you are still not seeing the format you want, experiment with changing the other options (above and below the highlighted box) from **Chop down if long** to **Wrap always**.

Comment: And "Method Annotations" for formatting annotations on methods

Comment: And have to do it also for class. Check this for more details: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206627789-Java-code-formatter-Annotations-on-a-single-line

Answer (score 22):

In IntelliJ 12 You can find it in setup here (bottom right):

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I think all the above answers are correct but here is step by step for Mac users:

1. Click on "IntelliJ IDEA"
2. Click on "Preferences"
3. Go "Code Style" on the left navigation window and you will see "Java" listed below it and Click on it !
4. Look for the header tab "Wrapping and Braces" on the right side of Preferences window.
5. At this point you want to look for the item called "Do not wrap after single annotation" under "Field annotations". click "ok" and you are done !

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Nothing seemed to work for me with version 2.3.3 or Android Studio.  I gave up and checked *Line breaks* under *Keep when reformatting*.  I just have to be very careful when I add line breaks.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

in 2023.2.2
Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces tab:
Set "Method annotations" to "Wrap always"