# No line break after @Override annotation?

Tags: java, ide, android-studio

When overriding methods, android studio automatically inserts a line break after the `@Override` annotation.

How can I have the `IDE` insert the `@Override` without the line break and have it immediately followed by the method declaration (ie on the same line ?):

```
@Override public Fragment getItem(int position) { ... }
```

instead of:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) { ... }
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

File -> Settings -> Code Style -> Wrapping and Braces -> Method annotations and set to *Do not wrap*.

**Note**: Changing the setting will not actually reformat all existing ones. It just won't be wrapped when inserted automatically by the IDE, as you want in your question. This applies to all annotations for methods.

[image]

Comment: Do the same with `Field annotations` to avoid line breaks for fields. This is helpful when using View Injectors, like `ButterKnife` or `Dagger`

Comment: When i generate interface methods, the @override for the generated methods are still on individual lines. Can i make them one line?

Comment: UPDATE in the new Android Studio:
File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java/Kotlin -> Wrapping and Braces -> The shown list will pop up.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to have it on the same line, but I would advise against it. It is a common convention to always have the annotation on a separate line.

- not following conventions without any reason to makes it inconvenient for developers working on several projects or changing project
- when you use many annotations the lines will very easily break ~120 chars, making the code less readable

if you still want them on the same line, this is a solution:
[Intellij code formatting, Java annotations on new lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284911/intellij-code-formatting-java-annotations-on-new-lines)

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly valid from the viewpoint of Java syntax to have @Override annotation on the same line as method signature. One thing to do is to tune your IDE autoformatiing settings.

Comment: Thanks, in fact I was actually wondering how to do it :).  Edited the question for clarity.