# Intelij 2016.2.5 code formatting wraps annotations in the same line

Tags: intellij-idea

I imported an Eclipse code style scheme to IJ 2016.2.5 community edition and it (wrongly) wraps annotations in the same line, e.g.

`@Override public Integer create(List<EventDto> events) {`

I went to **Preferences → Editor → Code Style → Java → Wrapping and Braces tab** and set **Do not wrap after single annotation** (as suggested by other answers [such as](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15284937/4828060)) and it still fails. Furthermore, every entry related to annotations in this menu, is set to **do not wrap**. Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should set the **Method annotations** parameter to **Wrap always**:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it still does not work for some types of annotations, e.g. @Autowired. Do you think this is due to Spring not being supported by the  community edition?

Comment: Unfortunately I've never used Community edition. But probably yes, here is [IDEA editions comparison list](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) and Spring Framework is supported only in Ultimate edition. As `@Autowired` is Spring's annotation, I think that may be the reason.