# Intellij with google-java-format - how to make Java annotations in new lines

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using `IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 (Community Edition)` on MacOs and install [google-java-format](https://github.com/google/google-java-format) plugin, however when I format the code by `Command + Shift + F`, it always puts my class member and its annotation on the same line, for example:

```
@NotNull private String someString;
```

Does anyone know how to configure in order to make them on 2 separate lines?

I follow the help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284911/intellij-code-formatting-java-annotations-on-new-lines), but it doesn't help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this issue before with `google-java-format` plugin. So try to uninstall that plugin and instead use the `intellij-java-google-style.xml`.

Can follow this [link](https://github.com/HPI-Information-Systems/Metanome/wiki/Installing-the-google-styleguide-settings-in-intellij-and-eclipse). I just recap here:

> Download the `intellij-java-google-style.xml` file from the http://code.google.com/p/google-styleguide/ repo.
>
> **Windows:**
> Copy it into your config/codestyles folder in your IntelliJ settings folder. Under Settings -> Editor -> Code Style select the google-styleguide as current code style for the Metanome project.
>
> **Macintosh:**
> Download it and go into Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style. Click on Manage and import the downloaded Style Setting file. Select GoogleStyle as new coding style.